# Python global/local scope in the interpreter? What sorcery is this

Tags: python, scope, global, local

Here's my simple script, called aScript.py:

```
a = 0

def load():
    global a
    a = 1

def plot():
    print a
```

Then in the python interpreter in do the following 4 commands:

```
>>>from aScript import *
>>>print a
>>>load()
>>>print a
```

Why does it print:

```
0
0
```

Instead of (which is what I expected btw):

```
0
1
```

I'm using python 2.6.

Thanks!

...Why does it print 0 0?

Comment: Interesting. Using Python 2.7 this works fine for me.

Comment: Same here: http://repl.it/R3q

Comment: -1; in Python 2.6 it works as expected too. Never seen so many upvotes for a question that's simply lying about the results.

Comment: It is just using the interpreter (after a from aScript import *) that it works differently, if I include it in the script it does indeed work fine...

Comment: Did you change the module to add `global` after the first time you imported it without restarting the interpreter?

Comment: No, not at all. I'm careful to save the script, close/re-open the interpreter after each modif... I've been at this for 30 mins, reading about variable scope and everything, and still no idea what's going on... (I'm a beginner in Python)

Comment: There's no version of Python that will print 2 `0`s if you actually import that exact code and run those commands. You're importing something else accidentally, most likely. Check your working directory and delete any `aScript.pyc` files.

Comment: I am building Python 2.6.8 on Ubuntu 13.10 ... to verify this code...

Comment: -1. I works as you expected on Python 2.6.8

Comment: My bad, messed up, you guys were right obviously, the question is why doesn't it print 0 0?

Comment: why do you expect 0 0?

Comment: Gaaa I messed up again, made a 2nd edit, I'm calling print a twice actually, and then it DOES print 0 twice, even after calling load()...

Comment: @user3545467 please delete the question and restart it with your *actual* code and expectations

Comment: Agree -- how about just delete the question and come back later after you've worked on this a bit more and read the docs on the global keyword.

Comment: I've cleaned the question, and already got an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` variables are only global in their own module, therefore `load()` only modifies the `a` variable inside `aScript`, not the imported `a`.

When you do `from aScript import *`, python iterates over `aScript`'s public variables and creates a copy of each in the current module, that is, it creates `__main__.a` equal to `aScript.a`. Now you call `load`, which is actually `aScript.load` which modifies its own `a` (`aScript.a`), but since it has no idea about `__main__.a`, the latter is left intact.

Comment: Thanks, I see! Then how can I do it such that the variable is really global, at the level of the interpreter?

Comment: @user3545467: I don't think there's a direct way - globals are bad idea mostly, and python doesn't support bad ideas. You can try hacking `__builtins__` though.

Answer (score 0):

global enables writeability of a global variable. Without it, the global variable is readable from function scope, but attempts to write it create a local var of same name